# org mode, export source blocks to tcolorbox instead of lstlisting

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I have an org document that contains #+begin_src blocks. These are placed in a \begin{lstlisting}[htbp]\begin{minted} environment when exporting to a latex document. Now there are two problems. First, this is a float environment, which is not good, since the code then no longer matches to the text, and second, the lstlisting is not suitable for long code blocks, which go over more than one page. Is there any way that codeblocks can be placed in \begin{tcolorbox} environment?

I would like to have an output that formats the codeblock something like this:

```
\begin{tcblisting}{
breakable,
minted language=python,
minted options={breaklines=true, breakanyware=true, linenos=true}}
<<content of code block>>
\end{tcblisting}
```